# Refresh a label with jQuery : text() or replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a label which is filled-up at the loading of the page, with something like :

```
onload = function() {
$('#mylabel').text($('#select').val());
}
```

I created an event triggered when the user modifies (clicks on) the "select" field, I want it to modify the label with id : #mylabel.

If I use the text() method, nothing happens (the label remains empty).

If I use replaceWith(), where I rewrite the tags, it works.

How is it possible ? Why text() doesn't work in this case ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you replicate the problem as jsfiddle? Did you try `.html()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: is #select a select menu? Try replace `$("#select").val()` with `$('#select:selected').val()`, and also as Michal said use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: using $('#select:selected').val() returns "undefined". Using .html() instead of .text() has the same effect as described above : the label remains empty, except at the loading of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Text seems to work for me.

```
$('body').on('change','select#select',function(){
   var thisvalue = $(this).val();
   $('h1#myLabel').text(thisvalue);
});
$(function(){
   var selectvalue= $('select#select').val();
   $('h1#myLabel').text(selectvalue);
});
```

See my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gametroll/eyndjs8g/)